# Object not mirroring as intended in Blender

Tags: mirror

I am making a character arm at right side and when mirroring the object, the mirrored object is not placed at correct position. I have read that the mirror modifier does mirroring with respect to the *Object Origin* (orange point). So i placed the orange point at the *3D cursor* and then did mirroring. Unfortunately this mirroring does not work on objects whict are rotated.

This is the result i am getting:

[image: Unwanted mirroring]

Desired result:

[image: Wanted result]

Comment: Your object is rotated, you have to apply the rotation with `Ctrl+A` *> Rotation* before  mirroring.

Comment: Wow that was quick. I think it worked. Can you explain Ctrl+A rotation and normal rotation (With R key pressed).

Comment: sure. will post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`Apply Rotation`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html) before you can properly use the [`Mirror Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html).

> [`Applying`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html) transform values essentially resets the values of object’s
> location, rotation or scale, while visually keeping the object data
> in-place. The object origin point is moved to the global origin, the
> rotation is cleared and scale values are set to 1.

[image]

Comment: Ok i got it, thanks.